# Change Netbeans Autocomplete

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

Is there a way to change the suggestions that NetBeans autocomplete suggests. For example when I type pu public static main is the first suggestion and I want to change it to suggest public.

Comment: I don't know, but you can try Ctrl+Space to bring up a selection option for `public static main`.

Answer (score 3):

First, to clarify what is happening, NetBeans provides code completion for the following by default:

- Typing **pu**[tab] will generate **public**
- Typing **psvm**[tab] will generate **public static void main(String[] args) {
  ${cursor}
  }**

However, when you type **pu** Auto Popup finds two potential matches which start with **pu**:

- **public**
- **public static void main(String[] args) {
  ${cursor}
  }**

For reasons I don't understand NetBeans employs a sort order which determines that **public static void...** precedes **public**, so you are being offered the unwanted option as the default in the Auto Popup.

There are (at least) three ways to address this, and you may not like any of them, but here goes anyway:

- You could simply turn off Auto Popup, then **pu**[tab] would automatically generate **public**. To do this, select **Tools -> Options -> Code Completion** tab **->** 
  Uncheck **Auto Popup on Typing Any Java Identifier Part**, then click **OK**. This fixes the problem, but you lose autocompletion.
- You could remove the mapping of **psvm** to **public static void...**. To do that, select **Tools -> Options -> Code Templates** tab, select the line containing the **Abbreviation** of **psvm** and click **Remove**, then click **OK**. With this approach you can turn code completion back on, but you will no longer be able to generate the **main()** method by typing **psvm**[tab].
- You could tweak the text generated by typing typing **psvm**[tab] so that it does not start with **public**. For example you could insert a leading space (" **public static void....**"), or change the declaration to "**static public void...**", which is perfectly valid for the main() method (though a bit unconventional). With this approach you can leave Auto Popup on, but you will not get **public static void...** as an option.

To change the expanded text generated by **psvm**, select **Tools -> Options ->** select the **Code Templates** tab, select the line containing the **Abbreviation** of **psvm** and then edit the text in the **Expanded Text** window. See the screen shot below where the **Expanded Text** has been subtly changed from "**public static void main(...**" to " **public static void main(...**" with a leading space.

[image: codeCompletion]

None of these are perfect solutions, but you may find that one of them is preferable to what you have now.

---

**Update:**

A fourth option, and perhaps the best one of all, is to simply change the abbreviation of **public** from **pu** to **pb**. To do that, select the existing **pu** abbreviation, copy its **Expanded Text** to the clipboard, click **Remove**, then click **New** to create the abbreviation **pb** and paste the clipboard into the **Expanded Text** field.